# How to pass object parameter with multiple values in azure devops api service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm trying to run a pipeline with object parameter using azure-devops-rest-6.0

```
- name: images
  displayName: docker images
  type: object
  default:
  - image1
  - image2
  - image3
```

but each time i pass this template parameter on my post request body, i get `Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value 'image1'"`

```
    "templateParameters": {
        "images": "image1"
    }
```

so i tried replacing it with array type but it throws error like `parameter must be provided.` for all fields which im sure i provided all fields with values.

```
    "templateParameters": {
        "images": ["image1"]
    }
```

did i missed something wrong when passing the values? what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Comment: yup your answer is more fancier than my original solution. thanks @KevinLu-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your YAML sample and Request body, you need to modify the format in your request body.

You can use the following format:

```
  "templateParameters": {
    "images": "[image1,image2]"
   }
```

Full example:

```
{
  "resources": {
    "repositories": {
      "self": {
        "refName": "refs/heads/main"
      }
    }
  },
  "templateParameters": {
    "images": "[image1,image2]"
   }


}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, your solution is much cleaner than my work around ```"images": "- image1\n - image2\n"```